# Restaurant e-menu using html and jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have been using jquery mobile for developing a restaurant e-menu for ipad and android tablets.I m done with UI but I need to add functionality to it.
I have some queries regarding this.

- I am using a mysql db to store the items, price, etc. and i'm reading it to a html page through php. Is it the best way to store the details of the dish in a db and call it to a html page? If not which is the best way?
- I need to display the items selected/ordered by the user in a separate page. Should I use forms? If not which is the best way to show the ordered items? How do I do that?

If there are any helpful links regarding my queries, Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: yes and yes. How you structure your db is important, but you will definitely use a DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question YES it is the right way,

For the second part I was going through a few sites last week and i came across a very special app  Check this link below.

- http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbklistselection-like-facebook-friends-selector.html

Comment: i was able to read the contents from db, and it is working with no problem. Can I get some more helpful links? I also need to add the total amount of the purchased order. But the plugin above does not post values.